# Silverlight bring element to front

Tags: silverlight, element

we have a project in which we have a rectangle and some buttons. When the program starts we are generating some Images. These Images are on top of the buttons, because they have been added after the buttons.
The problem is that we want to have the buttons in front of the images. In Winforms we could do this with button1.BringToFront, but this doesn't work in Silverlight. How can it be done?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could put all of your controls in a Canvas and use the Canvas.ZIndex property to control the level of each control.

Comment: @StewartSweet: you don't need to put controls in a `Canvas` to use `Canvas.ZIndex`.  `Canvas.ZIndex` works with all panels.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the z index to a large number using a call to Canvas.SetZIndex:

```
Canvas.SetZIndex(aUIControl, 100)
```